# How to format toString() method with "\n"?

Tags: java, formatting, format, newline, tostring

I have a `toString()` method where it returns information about ordering online. This returns the person's name, brand the person is shopping at, price of what they're buying, total price and if it's available or not.

My criteria is to have multiple output of the following based on how many people orders:

```
Amazon: Order #1001
Customer: "Name"
Brand: "Seller"
Price: $"Price in double"
"Name of item"
Total Price: $"Price in double"
```

I want so that if the person orders nothing, the "name of item" portion disappears and doesn't include the `"\n"`.

**Output Example:**

```
Amazon: Order #1002
Customer: Jane Doe
\nBrand: Nike
Price: $0.0
Total Price: $0.0

Amazon: Order #1001
Customer: Jane Doe
Brand: Nike
Price: $94.04
Nike Air Max 97
Total Price: $94.04

Amazon: Order #1001
Customer: Jane Doe
Brand: Nike
Price: $86.90
Nike Revolution 5
Total Price: $180.94
```

My output does everything as follows except it creates a new line when the person doesn't order anything. You can see this below where the first order has a space between price and total price.

**My output:**

```
Amazon: Order #1002
Customer: Jane Doe
Brand: Nike
Price: $0.0

Total Price: $0.0

Amazon: Order #1001
Customer: Jane Doe
Brand: Nike
Price: $94.04
Nike Air Max 97
Total Price: $94.04

Amazon: Order #1001
Customer: Jane Doe
Brand: Nike
Price: $86.90
Nike Revolution 5
Total Price: $180.94
```

This is my `toString()` method:

```
public String toString() {
    String item = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        s += s[i];
        if(i < currentNumOrders - 1) {
            item += "\n";
        }
    }  

    return app + ": Order #" + number + "\nCustomer: " + 
           name + "\nBrand: " + brand + "\nPrice: $" + 
           price + "\n" + item + "Total Price: $" + sum;       
}
```

Comment: It looks like your class has a list of items and your toString concatenates them together.  You can do that but a more traditional way would be to have each Order object return a smaller toString and then print them externally thru iteration.  Perhaps return a list of Orders.

Comment: *Price: $"Price in double"* - currency should not be represented using `float` or `double`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ternary condition to show `\n` only when neccessary:

```java
return app + ": Order #" + number + "\nCustomer: " + 
           name + "\nBrand: " + brand + "\nPrice: $" + 
           price + "\n" + (item.length() > 0 ? item + "\n" : "") + "Total Price: $" + sum;
```

Comment: Or, with a little rearranging, an if-statement.